# Control QProgressBar Width

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qprogressbar

I have a vertical QProgressBar that lives in a horizontal layout, between two QTextEdit objects. In Designer, I've changed the width of the progress bar using a stylesheet, which works to a degree - but I can't shrink the width below about 17 pixels. I'd like it to be very narrow - maybe around 5px or so - but changing the stylesheet and the minimum size in Designer just won't change it to be that narrow.

Comment: I changed the value of the Width field in designer instead of stylesheet. It works for me. Also, how are you changing the width from stylesheet? I wouldn't want to do it that way..

Answer (score 1):

You can change the size of any widget in a number of ways:

**Designer** - In the designer forms, you will find a width field under `Geometry`. Set the width you want to set here.

**Code** - There are a a number of accessible functions for most, if not all predefined widgets in Qt. [`Qwidget::setFixedWidth()`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setFixedWidth), or [`QWidget::setGeometry`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#geometry-prop) could be useful.

Keep in mind that whatever you set in code will generally take precedence over the value in designer, based on latest executed statement.

PS- I have tried but been unsuccessful in setting the size through stylesheet. I think it may be unreliable.